# ${var} Not Getting Replaced in Select onchange Event

Tags: select, grails, onchange

I have following select in a template that I render, passing i in the model. ${i} get's replaced with the value of i, as expected in most places. But ${i} is not getting replaced in the onchange event.

So,

```
<g:select class='setTagtypeValue-class'
        name='tagtype-${i}-header'
        from="${org.maflt.ibidem.Tagtype.list(sort:'tagtype').groupBy{it.tagtype}.keySet()}"
        value="${setTagtypeValue?.tagtype?.tagtype}"
        noSelection="${['null':'Select One...']}"
        onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'options', update:'tagtype-options-${i}',  
                    params:'\'tagtype=\' + this.value +\'&i=${i}\'' )}" />
```

gets rendered as:

```
<select name="tagtype-0-header" onchange="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:'tagtype=' + this.value +'&amp;i=${i}', url:'/ibidem/metadataSet/options',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#tagtype-options-${i}').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});" class="setTagtypeValue-class" id="tagtype-0-header">
<option value="null">Select One...</option>
<option value="abstract">abstract</option>
. . .
</select>
```

Notice that, for example, name has been set to "tagtype-0-header", but in the onchange I'm getting

```
data:'tagtype=' + this.value +'&amp;i=${i}'
```

Also note that when this template is used during Create, where the substition happens client side, everything works as expected. So the only problem is that during Edit, working server-side, ${i} isn't getting replaced within the onchange event.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already inside of a `${}`, the inner `${}` is going to be ignored.  Try this out:

```
<g:select class='setTagtypeValue-class'
    name='tagtype-${i}-header'
    from="${org.maflt.ibidem.Tagtype.list(sort:'tagtype').groupBy{it.tagtype}.keySet()}"
    value="${setTagtypeValue?.tagtype?.tagtype}"
    noSelection="${['null':'Select One...']}"
    onchange="${remoteFunction(action:'options', update:'tagtype-options-' + i,  
                params:'\'tagtype=\' + this.value +\'&i=' + i + '\'' )}" />
```

Comment: That does the trick. Unfortunately, to avoid a lot of other changes, I need to have 2 selects, wrapped in <g:if>. But it works!